# jQuery how to check if all element in array have specific class

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to check of all the elements inserted into an array have a class.
The code I have so far for the array is this:

```
var ids = ['#biography', '#videogallery', '#pubblications', '#contacts', '#resume'];
var currentElem = "";

function test(){
    $(ids.join()).each(function() {
        var currentElem = $(this);
    })
};
```

The problem is that now I'm a bit stuck. I mean, what should I write so that an `if` statement check if all of the elements with the ids in the array have "test" class?

Something like:

- if #biography as class "test"
- if #videogallery as class "test"
- etc
- if all of them as the "test" class, then run a function
- if even one doesn't, then run else.

Hope it's not too confusing. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why in first place are you using an array and not a jQuery set?

Comment: use .hasClass method of jQuery. it checks whether element has particular class or not. Otherwise use .is method of jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to identify the elements with the class, then compare the `length` property of filtered element and array.

```
var elementsHavingTestClass = $(ids.join()).filter('.test');    

if(elementsHavingTestClass.length == ids.length){
    //All elements have the class
    //Do something
}else{
    //Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function and get elements with the class and Compare the lengths.

```
elementsWithTest = $(ids.join()).filter('.test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list to only have elements with the 'test' class and then compare the size against the original:

```
var filtered_arr = $(ids.join()).filter('.test');
if(filtered_arr.length === ids.length) {
    // All have the class
}
else {
    // At least one doesn't have the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This might help*

```
function test() {
    var flag = true;
    $(ids.join()).each(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("yourClass"))
          {
            flag=false;
            break;
          }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: This will always return `true`

Comment: Now it will return nothing. You should test your code before posting it ;)

Comment: Nope... http://jsfiddle.net/18ub89ek/ -> "Uncaught SyntaxError: **Illegal break statement**"

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you place the same class to all yours Ids, for example class="landingPageForm", and then you ask if the other class test is present.

```
// It returns true if it's present, otherwise false
$('.landingPageForm').hasClass('test')
```

And if you want to do it more stylist you can loop through them verifying if they contain your class test. In my example I used the class error.
Below, loginFormAssertion is a function which verify if your inputs contain the class error.

```
function loginFormAssertion() {
  const fieldsForm = Array.from($(".landingPageForm"));
  return fieldsForm.map(el => { return el.className }).filter(el => el.includes('error'))
}
```

Now let's simulate you invoke that function when you click on the login button.

```
 $(".login").click(function() {
    let isThereErrors= loginFormAssertion().length >0
    // You can remove ">0" above and ask in the "if" below in case you want to know exactly the number of times is present the class
    if(isThereErrors) // do this
    else // do this
})
```